# Alert View button actions not working

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uialertview

I am using an Alert view to bring up a popup where the user will choose to either select a photo from the library or take a photo to use. The alert view comes up fine, but when I select a button the code I have implemented is not run?!?

for some reason the `- (void)picturePopup:(UIAlertView *)picturePopup clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex` does not seem to even get run!? I'm lost run over lots of tutorials and websites but can't see why?! please help!

code:
.m

```
#import "LoadViewController.h"

@implementation LoadViewController

int imageCase;

- (IBAction)pick:(id) sender {

    imageCase = [sender tag];

    UIAlertView *picturePopup = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
    initWithTitle:@"Select Photo" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Choose From Library", @"Take Photo", nil];
    [picturePopup show];

}

- (void)picturePopup:(UIAlertView *)picturePopup clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

        NSLog(@"***************getting here****************");

    if (buttonIndex == 1) {

        NSLog(@"***************library****************");
        //Library Picker
        UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker.delegate = self;
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    }
    if (buttonIndex == 2) {
        NSLog(@"***************camera****************");
        //Camera
        UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker.delegate = self;
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    }



}


- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo {
    switch (imageCase) { 
        case 1: 
            imageView1.image = image;
            break; 
        case 2: 
            imageView2.image = image;
            break; 
    }

    [picker.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}


- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
    [picker.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}



@end
```

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface LoadViewController : UIViewController <UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate> {
    IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView1;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView2;
}


- (IBAction)pick:(id) sender;

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the actual delegate method:

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

This is not the same as:

```
- (void)picturePopup:(UIAlertView *)picturePopup clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

The method signatures are different. `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:` vs. `picturePopup:clickedButtonAtIndex:`

You can rename the variable you just can not change the method signature.

Comment: That worked thanks for your help. Although now I have another problem, The image picker comes up but once I select an image or hit cancel the image picker view won't close! I think its a problem with this piece of code but not sure why? `[picker.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

Comment: Picker was displayed modally. It's `parentViewController` property is nil. You could use `[picker dismiss...` or `[self dismiss...`

Answer (score 0):

This is sort of off topic, but I notice you didn't synthesize ***imageView1** and ***imageView2**. lol

Comment: I wasn't aware you could synthesize a UIImageView?! Would I do this the same way an object variable?

Comment: Yes, just under implementation like usual.`@implementation @synthesize imageView1, imageView2;`